# How to get custom campaign URL from AppStore?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I am implemented Google Analytics for campaign. Now scenario is User A  share Campaign link via any network to User B. When User B click on that link it redirect to AppStore, now I want to get Campaign parameters in my app. So how can I get that and how to debug that URL with parameter.

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should custom the Campaign link not direct to AppStore.
Your campaign link should be link to your site, and your site after get all the parameter, it will auto redirect to the Appstore

Comment: Ok, but can we get that url in our app when user open it from AppStore. I want utm_source and campaign_name parameters which appended in that link.

Comment: @ashwini : did you check this document 
 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns

Comment: yes I went through that link. but I want to get that URL when user launch application through App Store. how get that URL.

Comment: @ashwini I think you can't. You can only know if app has been installed before, and user B click to the banner. Google said it here `After an app has been installed, it may be launched by referrals from ad campaigns, websites, or other apps. In this scenario, referring traffic sources or marketing campaigns can be attributed to user activity in subsequent sessions by setting the campaign fields on a tracker directly.`

Comment: I have shared link through email, whatsApp or other social network to the user. And then user install the app from that link then I want that parameters.

Comment: @ashwini yeah, I know. It's difficult. If you want to know user B has install the app from campaign of A or not, you must do many thing, and It can be wrong. First, you direct your invite link to your site, record user B's ip. Then your site will redirect to Appstore. When user B download and run it first time, you must call to your site to re-check the ip too. But if has user C using same LAN network, it will be wrong